# date format parses the 12th hour value (hh) to 00

Tags: java, date

date format parses the 12th-hour value (hh) to 00 while applying the format as "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss" but it does not parse the 13th hour to 1 PM. PFB the sample code piece.

```
Date testDate = DateUtil.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss", "2010-07-09T12:50:58");
```

can you please let me know why this is converting so?

Comment: Are you using JCalendar?  Might be helpful to mention it.

Comment: What is `DateUtil`? Not standard Java, Apache commons?

Answer (score 9):

You should use `HH` instead of `hh`. The former is for 24-hour clock, the latter for a 12-hour clock.

See the [javadoc for SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

**EDIT**: Note that the problem may be at the other end too. To get the hour from a `java.util.Date`, you can set it on a `Calendar` object and call `get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)`. Note that `get(Calendar.HOUR)` will give you the 12-hour rather than the 24-hour.

Comment: If 'hh is for 12-hour clock, why its not converting 13, 14 to 1,2 PM respectively?

Comment: Because 13 and 14 are not valid items for a 12-hour clock value.

Comment: Thanks Simon, But Will this method wont throw exception for invalid inputs like 13 amd 14. As i am new to java can you please explain a bit more...

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not familiar with `DateUtil`, but `SimpleDateFormat` seems to parse 13 as 1pm even with `hh`. WHat is the full package name of `DateUtil`? Also, how are you displaying the parsed date to check the hour? You need `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` rather than `Calendar.HOUR` to extract the hour in 24-hour format.

Comment: Simon, PFB the code snippet.. import java.text.ParseException; import java.util.Date; public class Smallh { public static void main(String[] args) { try { Date testDate = DateUtil.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss", "2010-07-09T01:50:58"); System.out.println("***" + testDate); } catch (ParseException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } } }

Comment: OK, so you're not importing `DateUtil`. Is it a class in your own package? (Also, the code snippet is better added to the body of your question.)

Comment: DateUtil is a class in my own package & class has the parse method.. PFB the DateUtil class ... 
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.ParsePosition;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
public class DateUtil { private DateUtil() { } public static Date parse(String strDatePattern,String sDate) throws ParseException { SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(strDatePattern); return sdf.parse(sDate); } }

Answer (score 1):

```
    DateFormat inputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss");
    Date date = inputFormatter.parse("2010-07-09T13:50:58");
    DateFormat outputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss a");
    System.out.println(outputFormatter.format(date));
```

The output is:

```
2010-07-09T01:50:58 PM
```

It reads in 13 fine, and outputs 01 (PM).

Comment: Hi, Actually i am using the below code snippet..i.e here date format object is not used, also in my scenario the output of DateUtil.parse(date_format,dateInput1) is compared with the output of DateUtil.parse(date_format,dateinput2) 

import java.text.ParseException; import java.util.Date; public class Smallh { public static void main(String[] args) { try { Date testDate = DateUtil.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss", "2010-07-09T01:50:58"); System.out.println("***" + testDate); } catch (ParseException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } } }

Comment: why can't you use SimpleDateFormat?

Answer (score 0):

As you are reading a time with timezone and printing with your locale, the system transforms time to your local in Uruguay.

You need to create a calendar with custom locale and timezone in order to keep it consistent:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String dateStr = "Tue, 04 Aug 2015 12:09:10 GMT";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date d = format.parse(dateStr);
    System.out.println("The current time is: " + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds());
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"), Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.setTime(d);
    System.out.println("The current time is: " + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
}
```